remove features with the same names in three different data frames in R
I am trying to do a MOFA analysis. But when I try to do the enrichment analysis, I got an error:

Error in run_enrichment(model, view = "Proteome", factors = 2:3, feature.sets = reactomeGS,  :
Feature names in feature.sets do not match feature names in model).

I think this happened when creating Mofa object, I got warning:

Warning: There are duplicated features names across different views. We will add the suffix _view only for those features)

I have three omics data and I would like to remove the duplicate features in all three omics.
I did list
df_list <- list(RNAseq = RNAseq, methylation = methylation, Proteome = Proteome)
df_list <- purrr::imap(df_list, ~ .x[, !duplicated(colnames(.x))])

 

How can I extract each data frame from the list to be used in the model

Can you show how str(MOFAobject@data) looks like? You probably have features in columns and samples in rows, which should be the other way around.

samples in columns and features in rows
